# The separating line on the tableview does not appear right

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, tableview, cell

The separation line on the tableview does not seem right on my project. I have no idea, but the separation line does not start from an edge of the screen. There is a little space at the beginning. Could someone please give me an advice why this is happening or what have I done wrong?

Comment: IF you are seeing this in iOS7 then it's default behaviour in iOS7.

Comment: I was seeing this is iOS7 indeed. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a stylistic change Apple introduced with iOS 7. From the [iOS 7 UI Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/ContentViews.html):

> Separators in iOS 7 are thinner, narrower, and lighter in color than
>   separators in iOS 6.
>       By default, the separator is inset from the left edge of the table view.